# How to get query for dates equals today in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, time, android-sqlite

How to make the query to retrieve from database only the records that have the time equals to 'today'. I store my dates as text(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) ?

Here is how my table looks like:

```
// TABLE EVENT
private static final String TABLE_EVENT = "event";
private static final String TABLE_EVENT_ID = "_id";
private static final String TALBE_EVENT_START_TIME = "start_time";
private static final String TALBE_EVENT_END_TIME = "end_time";
private static final String TALBE_EVENT_NOTE= "note";

  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_EVENT + " ("
        + TABLE_EVENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_START_TIME + " text not null, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_END_TIME + " text not null, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_NOTE + " text not null"
        +");";
```

I tried with

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.start_time = DATE('now');
```

But didnt work..

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_EVENT + " ("
        + TABLE_EVENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_START_TIME + " text not null, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_END_TIME + " text not null, "
        + TALBE_EVENT_NOTE + " text not null"
        +");";
```

Replace Create table query with this and it should work fine.

You have added extra comma at the end of note.

Answer (score 2):

Your query won't work as date in your database is stored as **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**, while [`SQLite DATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function returns date in format **yyyy-MM-dd**, *that too in [Universal Coordinated Time (UTC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)*. 
 
So, if you want to compare `event.start_time` with current date, store your date in format **yyyy-MM-dd** and run query as:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.start_time = DATE('now', 'localtime');
```

`localtime` to  compensate for your local timezone.

P.S. please report the problem correctly such as logs, error etc. **But didnt work..** doesn't specifies your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I store dates as `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`. Thus,
   `where mydate = '20180111000000' and mydate <= '20180111000000' and mydate >= '20180111000000'`

It just plain WORKS all the time.  You may only need to write a parser to handle how users might enter their dates so you can convert them to `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`.

**note** last 6 zero indicates HHmmss

or if you want to use only date function then refer this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: How excatly is your query for today dates when you store dates as YYYYMMDDHHmmss where mydate >= '20180111000000' and mydate <='20180112000000' ?

Comment: refer the link that I have post, you will find ans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get by datetime then you column format should be

TALBE_EVENT_START_TIME + "  DATETIME, " not in text and

SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.start_time = Datetime('now');